# Are there interesting maps between groups preserving non-equality that are not homomorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, logic

A homomorphism is generally defined as a map that preserves equality. That is, for groups $G,H$, a map $\phi : G \to H$ is a homomorphism if $ab=c \implies \phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi(c)$. Is there a notion of a map $\rho : G \to H$ such that $ab\neq c \implies \rho(a)\rho(b) \neq \rho(c)$? Are there examples apart from injections? That is, a map $\phi$ that preserves non-equality but *not* equality? That is, for some $a,b,c \in G$, we have $ab = c$, but $\rho(a)\rho(b) \neq \rho(c)$?

Comment: Sure, you can define it, but why would you want to?

Comment: It seems like a natural-enough construction. It has the property that if you can show two things are equal in the H, then their preimages in G must be equal. I changed the question to a better one: do interesting such maps exist? Do such maps exist with some kind of comprehensible structure?

Comment: Actually, the only maps from $G$ to itself satisfying these properties are the automorphisms. If $\rho$ has nontrivial kernel, then for some $a,b \in G$, we have $a\neq b$ but $\rho(a) = \rho(b)$.

Comment: Note that the interesting part of "$ab=c \Rightarrow \phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(c)$" is not the _equality_, but the _group operations_ on each side. Exactly the same property can be written with only one equals sign: $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$, so it is quite disingenuous to speak of it as "preserving equality". What a group homomorphism does is **preserve the group operation**.

Comment: To strengthen Henning's comment: your statement "a homomorphism is generally defined as a map that preserves equality" is plain wrong. Homomorphisms are defined as maps that commute with algebraic operations ("operate then map" is equivalent to "map then operate").

Comment: Yes, I put it wrong. My poor choice of words comes from the following idea: a homomorphism $f$ induces a map $f_*$ between propositions in the alphabet of G and propositions in the alphabet of H, mapping symbols in the proposition to their images under $f$. A homomorphism $f$ has the property that true propositions of equality map to true propositions of equality under $f_*$.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of examples of such maps that are not homomorphisms.  For instance, you could let $h\in H$ be any non-identity element, and define $\rho(a)=h$ for all $a\in G$.  Or, for $G=H=(\mathbb{Z},{+})$, you could define $\rho(n)=3^{|n|}$.  (Both of these examples in fact have the even stronger property that $\rho(c)\neq \rho(a)\rho(b)$ for *all* $a,b,c\in G$.)  There are many other possibilities.  It seems unlikely that you can say very much about the structure of such maps in general.

Comment: Don't we have that $2\cdot 2 = 4$, and $\rho(2)\rho(2) = 3^23^2 = 3^4 = \rho(4)$?

Comment: "Multiplication" here is addition of numbers.